# "java.lang.NullPointerException" when trying to addLast() into a linkedlist

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I am trying to insert a new node at the end of a single linked list. But I keep getting the NullPointerException after compiled.

Here is the Node class.

```
class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = null;
    }
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    } 
    public void setData(int newx){
        data = newx;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n){
        next = n;
    }   
}
```

Here is the single LL class

```
public class SingleLL {
    protected Node head=null;
    protected Node tail=null;
    protected int size=0;

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public void addLast(int x){
        Node newnode = new Node(x);
        if(size==0){
            head = newnode;
        }
        else{
            tail.setNext(newnode);
            tail = newnode;
        }
        size = size+1;
    }
    public void addfirst(int x){
        Node newnode = new Node(x);
        if(size==0){
            tail = newnode;
        }
        else{
            newnode.setNext(head);
            head = newnode;
        }
        size = size+1;
    }
```

Method addFirst()works.
When I am trying to create a LL by addLast(), the NullPointerException appears. I think there must be some problem at `if(size==0){head = newnode;}`, but I cannot figure it out.

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        SingleLL myList = new SingleLL();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            myList.addLast(a[i]);
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both `addLast` and `addFirst`, you need to initialize both `head` and `tail` when the list is empty. Otherwise one or the other will never get set, and will lead to your `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// In your two add methods:
// addLast: because when size = 1, head equals tail
    if(size==0){
        head = newnode;
        tail = head;
    }
    // addFirst: because when size = 1, head equals tail
    if(size==0){
        tail = newnode;
        head = tail;
    }
```

Remember, NullPointException only will occur before "." just like tail.setNext(); Let's see, if size = 1, you call the addLast. Currently, head is the newnode which you have added, but tail is null. So when it use tail.setNext() (Actually, null.setNext()) will cause NullPointException.

Comment: Thank you for your explicit explanation. Really appreciate that!